# How to set custom value in php.ini (Piwik raw_post_data error)

Tags: matomo, fortrabbit

This is a specific questions regarding fortrabbit in combination with the analyctics platform Piwik.

During the installation I get this error:

```
[Failed] always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
To prevent some critical issue, you must set the following in your php.ini file: always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
After making this change, restart your web server.
```

I'm not able to set this value via the dashboard and workarounds don't work either like creating a user.ini with this said value into your Piwik root folder or creating a .htaccess in your Piwik root folder

This might be only an issue with PHP 5.6 see:
https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6465

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this issue other than switching back to PHP 5.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed the staff and asked if it is possible that they could set this variable for me.

And yes after only one day the process was done and I could proceed the Piwik installation.

Excellent service!

Comment: Where you had emailed? Actually i have got same problem in installing time

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you can do

```
ini_set("always_populate_raw_post_data",-1)
```

Instead in your php file

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Piwik states the same error :-/

Comment: Yes, i saw that this value can not ne changed at runtime. I don't think you can do anything except to report a bug to Fortrabbit by saying that this value cannot be changed at runtime

Answer (score 0):

First define .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username
<Files php.ini>` 
order allow,deny`
deny from all
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

----replace username with yours-----

then edit php.ini (first enable post reading)

```
   ;enable_post_data_reading = on
```

then,

```
always_populate_raw_post_data=-1
```

cheers!